# I'm having trouble validating my form for some reason the error messages do not appear when the forename or surname is not enterd

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function() {
            alert("submitted!");
        }
    });
    $().ready(function() {
        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#signupForm").validate({
            rules: {
                firstname: "required",
                lastname: "required",
            },
            messages: {
                firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
                username: {
                    required: "Please enter a username",
                    minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
                },
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="cmxform" id="signupForm" method="get" action="">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Validating a complete form</legend>
            <p>
                <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
                <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
                <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" />
            </p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</body>
```

Comment: If you're wondering why this is being downvoted - take a look at your 'question'. If you want some help take the trouble to edit this into a readable form.

Comment: @MikeW I have edited it. Hopefully it is more readable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trailing commas (`,`) are illegal in JavaScript. When you do something like this:

```
rules: {
    firstname: 'required',
    lastname: 'required',
}
```

the JavaScript engine will think that `},` is the next item in the `rules` object.

You need to do something like this:

```
rules: {
    firstname: 'required',
    lastname: 'required' // <-- no comma at end
}
```

Comment: I edited the code took out the trailing commas but erros are still not displaying                                 $.validator.setDefaults({
 submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }
});

$().ready(function() {
 $("#signupForm").validate({
 rules: {
  firstname: "required",
  lastname: "required"
  },
   messages: {
  firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
  lastname: "Please enter your lastname"
    },
 });
 });

Comment: Are there any errors in your JavaScript console (F12 -> Console in Chrome)?

Comment: No I have no idea what is wrong with it I may just keep at it :)